# How to convert from Access 2010 (.accdb) to Access 95/97 (.mdb)?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access, mdb

How can I convert an Access 2010 `.accdb` file to an Access 95/97 `.mdb` file?

Is there a conversion facility available within Office?

Comment: Access 2010 can convert back to Access 2000 with but no farther: choose File / Save and Publish to see the available formats. If you don't have Access 97-2000 on hand, [the answers to this StackOverflow questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172826/i-need-to-write-an-access-97-mdb-file) give some guidance on how to get the rest of the way to a 97 mdb.

Comment: @chuff: can Access 2000 convert back to 95/97?

Comment: Yes, see [this Microsoft link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office-2000-resource-kit/how-to-convert-an-access-2000-database-back-to-access-97-HA001138154.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible from within Microsoft Office.
If you need to get your data into a pre-2000 level of Access, it should be possible to export the data and then import it into a running copy of the older Access.
If there's only a single table, it shouldn't be that hard.
If there are multiple tables involved it might take a while. 
If you've got fancy forms or queries built in, it might take more than a while.